# Is there a code generation tool that accepts Excel files as input?

Tags: c#, excel, code-generation

I'm looking to generate some C# code based on Excel data. Basically the Excel sheet contains definitions of functions that need to be generated in C#.

My current experience with code generation is mainly with ORM's. But now the "input" is Excel data.

I'm asking this to prevent me from re-inventing the wheel. Reading data from Excel is easy, and generating C# also. But I'm a lazy programmer.

Is there a code generation tool that accepts Excel files as input?

Comment: Personally, I still don't see what do you expect from the tool you are looking for, how those functions are defined inside Excel sheet?

Comment: I have no input on the question... but having a excel file that "contains definitions of functions that need to be generated in C#" seems like something you'd read about on thedailywtf.com.  Eek!

Comment: Are you talking about creating the shell of functions, based on function definitions?  Or are you actually expecting the inner workings of the function to be written as well?

Comment: @akmad: You mean http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/BlackBerry-UI-Magic.aspx ?

Comment: @Akmad... Basically the generated functions are wrappers of functions calls to a webservice, these functions will be used from within an Excel sheet (automation-addin).
So yes it contains the definition of functions... Pardon my French ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use T4 templates. I know this too common/abstract answer, but this is the way, I think, and I don't think you can find something already exist for that purpose. Visual Studio 2008 has native supports for them. In your T4 template you can read excel file and then use its data to create any code file you want.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  How would you read the Excel file?  "Visual Studio 2008 has native supports" -- can you provide a link?

Comment: @Jess Chadwick: Try this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you will have to hand roll this solution. This does seem a little wonky, would be curious how you got in a situation where you are needing to do code gen based on Excel?!?

Comment: Sometimes it can be useful.  As an example, we have an Excel macro that generates domain object classes, data access helpers, data mapping definitions, and test cases for iBATIS.NET for a database schema pasted into to Excel.  Saves hand-coding thousands of lines of code.  Of course Excel is only one option, but it's handy nonetheless.

Comment: Cory's examples is a good one... And in general Excel is the language of the "business"! They are fluent in Excel, and using information stored in an Excel sheets can be very helpful.

Comment: Found this question on Google. I'm actually in a situation in which I have a SRS which defines 100s of classes and 1000s of properties, in tables. The specification is in a PDF format. Adobe Acrobat offers to extract tables from PDF's to Excel. From there I converted them to CSVs. I then wrote a python script to convert it to C# classes.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with this problem before, I suggest that you convert the excel file to a CSV.
Im my case, I transformed the CSV file into C# classes (which include property and method definitions).

Answer (score 0):

You may use DestallMaterials.CodeGeneration package.
It uses Blazor templates (and c# code) to generate source code files.
You may parse your excel and the feed it to a template, that will give you the code.